# react jsx and ternary operator issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, conditional-operator

pleaaase why i have always this error when i work with the ternary operator in a handle function were i want to set state of the class i don't have this problem with if() but in the exercice they require ternary operator

here is block were i use it :
handleChange=(e)=>{

```
    this.state.sports.forEach((element)=>{
      (e.target.value==element)?this.setState({sport:this.state.sport.push(element)})
      :false
    
    })
}
```

and this is the error that i got :
Line 11:11:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
thank you a lot for helping

Comment: this.setState({sport: [...this.state.sport, element]})

Comment: Why do you have to use a ternary?

Comment: `no-unused-expressions` is an eslint rule, this error is not a JS error and the code looks fine to me. (Though it would be clearer with an if / else since ternary expressions are more for assignment usually).

Comment: Unless `e.target.value` might not appear in `sports`, there’s no need for a conditional at all – this code could be entirely replaced by `this.setState({sport: [...this.state.sport, e.target.value]})` (no loop). Not plural kind of implies that it should actually be `this.setState({sport: e.target.value})`, though. Also, you’re already learning an outdated way of using React.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error from ESLint's [no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions) rule. The unused expression in question is: `false`. It's being flagged as unused because nothing happens to it. It's not assigned to anything, it's not returned, and it's not used in any subsequent code. It doesn't have any purpose and shouldn't be there.

The solution is to get rid of the unused expression. The readable way to do this would be to use an `if` instead:

```js
this.state.sports.forEach((element) => {
  if (e.target.value == element) {
    this.setState({sport: ...});
  }
});
```

The less readable but arguably cleverer way would be to use `&&` instead:

```js
this.state.sports.forEach((element) => {
  (e.target.value == element) && this.setState({sport: ...});
});
```

The expression to the right of `&&` will only be evaluated if the expression to its left is truthy.

---

As twharmon [hints at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77225180/react-jsx-and-ternary-operator-issues#comment136142702_77225180) in the comments above, there's a second problem with your code. You shouldn't be mutating `this.state.sport`, i.e. you shouldn't be calling `push` on it. Instead you should be creating a new array, which he does with the spread operator (`...`):

```js
this.setState({sport: [...this.state.sport, element]});
```

This is discussed in the React docs chapter [Updating Arrays in State](https://react.dev/learn/updating-arrays-in-state).